# Solving multiple systems using Cholesky factorization to find Inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, homework

I have a matrix:

```
A = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 5, 5, 5}, {1, 5, 14, 14}, {1, 5, 14, 30}}
```

I wrote code in Mathematica (mostly copying what professor gave us, I'm new to Mathematica) for finding the Cholesky factorization. So I have `L` and `L^T = U` such that `A = L U`.

I need to write more code to solve the systems `A x = e_1`, `A x = e_2`, `A x = e_3`, `A x = e_4`, where `e_1`, `e_2`, `e_3`, and `e_4` are the standard basis vectors in `R^4`.

I get that I need an intermediate form. I am setting up so that: `L g_1 = e_1` and `U x_1= g_1`, but I don't know how to code Mathematica to solve the system `L g_1 = e_1` (or the other, but I imagine I can learn from the first). My professor has this code in another file he used to solve an LU factorization, but it doesn't seem like enough

```
g1 = e1

For[i = 0, i <= n - 1, i++; 
  g1[[i]] = e1[[i]] - Sum[LL[[i, j]] g1[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}]]
```

I adapted it for my variables. Some help would be nice. I plan on hitting office hours this week, but I have three other problems to work out as well, and was hoping to catch a break on this one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `LUDecomposition` or `CholeskyDecomposition` directly?

Comment: ^ also I don't know why you need either of these anyway. Your problem just looks like `A.B == IdentityMatrix[4]`. The solutions to x1,x2,x3,x4 are the column vectors of `{{5/4, -(1/4), 0, 0}, {-(1/4), 13/36, -(1/9), 0}, {0, -(1/9), 25/
  144, -(1/16)}, {0, 0, -(1/16), 1/16}}` found here https://pastebin.com/G60a5qFB

Comment: The main idea is that solving when the matrix is upper or lower triangular is easier than the general case. The next idea is that solving A B  x = v, for (triangular) matrices A and B and right hand side v, can be split into solving A y = v (solve for y) and B x = y (now solve for x).

Comment: Beyond your specific question, I suggest that you pay some attention to MMA's variable naming conventions, which will help you start thinking with MMA.  A couple of examples... Capitalized names generally refer to system named expressions (e.g., variables or functions).  Also, MMA will not recognize `e_1` as a variable name but will rather evaluate it as  `e_ * 1`.

Comment: Your For-loop displays invalid syntax. The semicolon should be a comma.